# Why am I getting the following error when running Google App from eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I did a search and found [QuickTip: VerifyError with jdk 7](http://vikashazrati.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/quicktip-verifyerror-with-jdk-7/):

> If you are struggling with the following kind of error
>
> `java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 6 bla bla bla …`
>
> then a simple solution is to add the following default JVM argument **`-XX:-UseSplitVerifier`**
>
> If you are doing it in eclipse, like i was, then goto Window -> Preferences -> Installed JREs -> and add the default parameter.
>
> What does this setting do? Oracle [just mentions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) that it a new type checker with StackMapTable attributes. Huh! Enjoy! It is Oracle now.

However, when I go to the Installed JREs settings it says `An error has occurred when creating this preference page`

I started learning about Google App Engine and began with Google's CodeLabEx0, and I think it worked out fine because I saw on my browser what I was supposed to see. But when I moved on to the second chapter CodeLabEx1, there's an error that won't allow me to create any products or items through the browser interface. Then I looked at the eclipse console and saw this:

```
Oct 28, 2011 11:40:30 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Oct 28, 2011 11:40:31 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\rock84\Downloads\CodeLabEx1\CodeLabEx1\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Oct 28, 2011 11:40:31 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\rock84\Downloads\CodeLabEx1\CodeLabEx1\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
Oct 28, 2011 4:40:31 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
Oct 28, 2011 11:40:59 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error for /product
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 48 in method com.google.appengine.codelab.ProductServlet.doPut(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V at offset 38
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:351)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I have no idea what this could be. This is a fresh install of Eclipse 3.7 with the following installed software:

- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
- Google App Engine Java SDK 1.5.5
- Gooogle Plugin for Eclipse 3.7
- Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.4.0

I'm on Windows 7 64-bit with Java version 1.7.0

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. It's what I wrote at the very top. Turns out I was adding the argument to the wrong eclipse installation. It works now.

"If you are struggling with the following kind of error
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 6 bla bla bla ….
then a simple solution is to add the following default JVM argument -XX:-UseSplitVerifier
If you are doing it in eclipse, like i was, then goto Window -> Preferences -> Installed JREs -> and add the default parameter.
What does this setting do? Oracle just mentions that it a new type checker with StackMapTable attributes. Huh! Enjoy! It is Oracle now."
Thanks to this dude: http://vikashazrati.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/quicktip-verifyerror-with-jdk-7/

Answer (score 8):

This is also possible by changing your run configuration:
Run > Run configurations

Pick your Web Application project from the left, open the Arguments tab and add the -XX:-UseSplitVerifier argument to the VM arguments.

The benefits of this approach is also its downside: it only applies to this project, instead of an entire VM installation.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem when deploying my GWT app in GAE and I was using JDK 7. Switching the project to JDK 6 solved that issue (I forgot that at this time only JDK 5 and 6 is supported by GAE).

Comment: Also, see the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/installing) for supported version of Java.