# No Coverage in EclEmma

Tags: junit, code-coverage

> I have a list of JUnit files and I want to measure code coverage using
>   EClEmma.

So I installed the plugin to Eclipse IDE.

The Coverage button is present in my IDE.

To measure coverage I just selected the JUnit file and pressed the Coverage button.

It launches the tests successfully.

But it shows an error called **'initializationError'** and some poor coverage percentage (.2), possibly missed many of the coverage and it shows many of the code as not covered.

I don't know how to rectify this problem.

**How to run coverage using EclEmma ?**

*Also I added the files for instrumentation and tried but it doesn't work.*

Comment: As shown in a post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936006/why-am-i-getting-the-following-error-when-running-google-app-from-eclipse             I just added the JVM parameter and now EclEmma runs fine. The main reason for this error is my jdk version is 1.7 (sun/oracle version). Thanks for the post.

Comment: And now I can able to measure the coverage information using EclEmma.