# Google App Engine - Servlet (Error: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 44 in method test.)

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, servlets, cloud

Hi I have th following `Servlet` in a new Google App Engine (SDK 1.6.6) project on Eclipse:

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestStorageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        try {
            writer.write("Hello");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            writer.write("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
             writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Such a servlet is working fine on Tomcat (as a normal Java Web Project)m but in Google App Engine Project I face the following 500 Error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /teststorage. Reason:

    Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 44 in method test.TestStorageServlet.doGet(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V at offset 25
Caused by:

java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 44 in method test.TestStorageServlet.doGet(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V at offset 25
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:369)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Powered by Jetty://
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are compiling with JDK7. http://java.dzone.com/articles/javalangverifyerror-expecting

Try switching to JDK6.

**Update**: this answer is now old and not relevant anymore. The solution with jdk7 seems to be to add `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` to your JVM parameters.

See this question for more info: [Why am I getting the following error when running Google App from eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936006/why-am-i-getting-the-following-error-when-running-google-app-from-eclipse)

Comment: javac source="1.6" target="1.6"

Comment: java 6 has been deprecated on GAE. Same error for me: https://gist.github.com/ZiglioNZ/bd1d7d424727b3f26c64

Comment: My answer is more than a year old and not relevant anymore. See this link for possible solutions (+comment): http://java.dzone.com/articles/javalangverifyerror-expecting

Comment: @PeterKnego thank you. The flag "-XX:-UseSplitVerifier" will fix the problem on the development server (if Oracle keeps it going). What about GAE's development server, over which we have little control?

Comment: I've created a Gist with this error. I'm looking at the bytecode of various classes. I can't point out where the inconsistency is. All I know is that GAE's classes are version 50, not 51, so they contain no stackmaps https://gist.github.com/ZiglioNZ/bd1d7d424727b3f26c64