# How to set a JVM option in Jenkins globally for every job?

Tags: java, maven, configuration, jenkins, jvm-arguments

I've recently installed a new JDK (1.7u9), and I got some very strange `VerifyError`s. [In a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936006/why-am-i-getting-the-following-error-when-running-google-app-from-eclipse) I found that it could help me if I use a `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` magic switch for the compilation.

**What I would like to do is to set this Java option globally in Jenkins, but haven't found any configurations for it.** Can someone help me out how can I do this?

The closest thing I was able to come up with is to set the argument through Maven, but I have to do it for each project configuration - and I'd like to avoid that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which application server do you deploy the Jenkins? Tomcat, GF or other?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Under the main menu item `Manage Jenkins`->`Configure System` you can set it in the box for `Global MAVEN_OPTS`.

It is a bit unclear whether you want the option turned on for the Jenkins container itself or only the jobs running in it, but if the latter and you're only running maven jobs, that's what I would do.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks, I believe this will be the solution. I wanted to set JVM arguments for different JDKs in Jenkins, but wasn't able to locate such settings. However, I can define it for Maven globally, that's enough.

Comment: This solved my issue with OSX 10.8.3 running Jenkins 1.514 and JDK 1.6.0_45

Comment: Seemed to be the only thing that worked for me. Pretty easy to go wrong with this one.

Answer (score 5):

If you deploy the Jenkins to the Tomcat or Glassfish, I would like to suggest you to set further configuration as the following:-

#### The Tomcat

Set the environment variable named **CATALINA_OPTS**, e.g.

```
SET CATALINA_OPTS="-XX:-UseSplitVerifier"
EXPORT CATALINA_OPTS
```

#### The Glassfish

Edit the [your_domain]/config/domain.xml

```
<java-config ....>
    ....
    <jvm-options>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</jvm-options>
</java-config>
```

Anyhow if you deploy it to another application server, please refer to your application server administrator guide to configure further JVM options.

#### UPDATED:

If you only would like to apply this JVM option to the Maven project, please set the environment variable named **MAVEN_OPTS**, e.g.

```
SET MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:-UseSplitVerifier"
export MAVEN_OPTS
```

I hope this may help.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows there's a **jenkins.xml** in Jenkins home directory. Simply add the required JVM options under arguments tag:

```
<arguments>
    -Xrs -Xmx256m -XX:-UseSplitVerifier 
    -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle 
    -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080
</arguments>
```

For most of the Linux distributions, modify *JENKINS_ARGS* inside file:
    **/etc/default/jenkins** (or jenkins-oc)

For CentOS, modify *JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS* inside file:
    **/etc/sysconfig/jenkins** (or jenkins-oc)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the only way to set system-wide JVM properties in Jenkins is with a [Groovy Script](http://www.keypressure.com/blog/jenkins-system-properties/) .

Create a `init.groovy.d` in Jenkins home and place a groovy file in it (`load-properties.groovy`). In the Groovy script, set system properties programmatically (see [link above](http://www.keypressure.com/blog/jenkins-system-properties/) for details):

```
       props.each { key, value ->
        System.setProperty(key, value)
```

The above solution saved my day as I needed to disable `jsse.enableSNIExtension` during SCM checkout and it should be available to the SVN plugin, not to Maven.

There's a `config.xml` file with `jdks/jdk/properties` XML tags, but it's undocumented.

Comment: The config.xml would be good except even today I can't locate documentation for it.  I will try the groovy method.