# Jenkins job with "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" when Checkmarx report is generated

Tags: java, ubuntu, jenkins, checkmarx

My Jenkins is running in an Ubuntu server instance. At the completion, when a Checkmarx report is being generated, I get a `Java heap space` issue as shown in the screen shot:

[image: Jenkinks java heap space Error]

Can someone help me how to increase Java heap space in Checkmarx?

To read the Atlassian KB article "[Scan Fails with Java Heap Space Exception](https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KC/pages/7602225/Scan+Fails+with+Java+Heap+Space+Exception)" an account seems to be necessary.

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Heap space means that you need to increase the amount of heap space allocated to Jenkins.To add more Java heap space, increase the value of the -Xmx Java parameter
Try setting this parameter to 1 GB (1048MB) and restart jenkins

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Builds+failing+with+OutOfMemoryErrors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read more about what is OutOfMemoryError [here](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space). Jenkins itself run as a Java process and if your Jenkins job is also a java process, both of them could cause out of memory Error.

By seeing the log it looks like your job is running into the error. So read also about [How to set a JVM option in Jenkins globally for every job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930529/how-to-set-a-jvm-option-in-jenkins-globally-for-every-job).

**Edit:** If your Jenkins process itself running into OutOfMemoryError, then refer to [Increase heap size in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java) on how to increase the JVM heap size for Java processes.

Normally `-Xmx2048M` is used to specify the max heap size for a java process, in my example i am setting it to 2048 MB. Depending on your configuration, you specify this value in different ways.

Comment: I wanted to handle this error in checkmarx side.I found this post https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/display/KC/Scan+Fails+with+Java+Heap+Space+Exception#

Comment: @NirangaSandaruwan , cool basically as i pointed out if its ultimately happening because java process doesn't have enough memory. as in your case you are scanning log files, which is a memory intensive operation as it will create try to create a buffer in memory.

Comment: @NirangaSandaruwan That's a dead link.  Do you have an updated link that works?